Encountering Recursion Depth error on gathering supposedly "cancelled" tasks
I have been trying to understand async programming in Python. Now I have this simple code which simulates a code I am working on.
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run_loop, args=(self.loop,))
        self.thread.start()
        self.websocket = None  # Simulate the websocket attribute

    def run_loop(self, loop):
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        loop.run_until_complete(self.close())

    def close(self):
        """
        Close the WebSocket connection and cancel all tasks.
        """

        def stop_loop(loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop):
            loop.stop()
            loop.close()

        async def cleanup():
            if self.websocket and not self.websocket.closed:
                await self.websocket.close()
            tasks = [t for t in asyncio.all_tasks(self.loop) if not t.done()]
            console_logger.debug(f"Found {len(tasks)} tasks to cancel.")

            for task in tasks:
                console_logger.debug(f"Cancelling task {task}")
                task.cancel()
                # assert task.cancelled() is True

            console_logger.debug("Starting cleanup tasks")
            await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
            console_logger.debug("Cleanup complete")
            self.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(stop_loop, self.loop)

        future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(cleanup(), self.loop)
        future.result()
        self.thread.join()


# Example usage
example = Example()
example.close()

The issue here is that on running this code, I am getting the following error:
2024-05-31 21:35:20,860 - console_logger - DEBUG - Found 1 tasks to cancel.
2024-05-31 21:35:20,860 - console_logger - DEBUG - Cancelling task <Task pending name='Task-1' coro=<Example.close.<locals>.cleanup() running at /home/user/temp.py:51> cb=[_chain_future.<locals>._call_set_state() at /home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/asyncio/futures.py:394]>
2024-05-31 21:35:20,860 - console_logger - DEBUG - Starting cleanup tasks
Exception in callback <_asyncio.TaskStepMethWrapper object at 0x721298c645e0>()
handle: <Handle <_asyncio.TaskStepMethWrapper object at 0x721298c645e0>()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/asyncio/events.py", line 88, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/asyncio/tasks.py", line 721, in cancel
    if child.cancel(msg=msg):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/asyncio/tasks.py", line 721, in cancel
    if child.cancel(msg=msg):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/asyncio/tasks.py", line 721, in cancel
    if child.cancel(msg=msg):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  [Previous line repeated 495 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded


Upon searching a bit on the internet, I found out that the tasks not cancelling might have something to do with the error. So I put an assertion check. In which case, I get the following:
2024-05-31 21:30:56,520 - console_logger - DEBUG - Found 1 tasks to cancel.
2024-05-31 21:30:56,520 - console_logger - DEBUG - Cancelling task <Task pending name='Task-1' coro=<Example.close.<locals>.cleanup() running at /home/user/temp.py:51> cb=[_chain_future.<locals>._call_set_state() at /home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/asyncio/futures.py:394]>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/temp.py", line 69, in <module>
    example.close()
  File "/home/user/temp.py", line 62, in close
    future.result()
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 456, in result
    return self.__get_result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 401, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/home/user/temp.py", line 54, in cleanup
    assert task.cancelled() is True
AssertionError


But the program still keeps running, and I need to Ctrl + C to stop it.
I am a very beginner in all these, so I don't have a good understanding, but I guess the tasks which I want to cancel aren't getting cancelled (which is also mentioned in the Python documentation that task.cancel() doesn't guarantee cancellation). How do I deal with a situation like this?

This thing is actually very twisted. You should (1) create  a new thread; (2) run an asyncio loop from within that thread ,with asyncio.run.  No need to use "call_soon_thread_safe" in that code. Moreover, your "close" method is not async, but you are trying to call it as if it where in one point, and as if not in another, and from two different threads.
Also, in this minimal code you create no other tasks but for the cleanup() function itself, and at some point inside cleanup you want to await all unfinished tasks: that should be where you get your recursion error: how can the cleanup function await for itself to be resolved inside its body?
(If you didn't get a recursion error, you'd get a deadlock with a stalled eventloop anyway).
It is complicated to try to "fix"this code, because it only contains calls to shutdown and cancel stuff, and never "begins" anything (but the cleanup itself) - even more than once.
But adding some stub methods for "things to be done" a more straightforward version of your code could look like:
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        # setup needed attributes, if any:
        ...
        
    def run(self):
        # starts the thread where the asyncio loop will run
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run_loop)
        self.thread.start()
    
    def run_loop(self, loop):
        # This stats the loop in the same thread it will run:
        # calling `asyncio.run` in place of `run_until_complete` will handle
        # the asyncio loop shutdown when things are done
        asyncio.run(self.do_stuff())
        
    def close(self):
        try:
            asyncio.call_soon_threadsafe(self.shutdown, self.loop)
        except RuntimeError:
            console_logger.warn("Loop had been previously closed")
        # only returns on the main thread when the loop shut-down is complete:
        self.thread.join()
    
    def shutdown(self):
        # shutdown will run in the same thread as the asyncio loop,
        # but as a synchronous callback - so it does not have to cancel itself:
        
        tasks = [t for t in asyncio.all_tasks(self.loop) if not t.done()]
        console_logger.debug(f"Found {len(tasks)} tasks to cancel.")

        for task in tasks:
            console_logger.debug(f"Cancelling task {task}")
            task.cancel()
            
    async def do_stuff(self):
        # Since "run_loop" does not get a chance to annotate the running
        # loop to be used in "self.shutdown" we do that here:
        self.loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        
        # setup websocket server
        ...
        try:
            while True:
                # do whatever is to be done serving sockets or else:
                ...
                # and at least in on point, yield to the asyncio loop
                    await asyncio.sleep(0)
        except CancelledError:
            # Stop websocket when we are cancelled:
            if self.websocket and not self.websocket.closed:
                await self.websocket.close()
            raise
    


# Example usage
example = Example()
try:
    example.run()
# other code for your the main thread here

finally:
    example.close()



Now it should be "untangled" and run fine.

Thank you so much for the detailed response. Really means a lot. I am and will be going through this answer quite a few more times, to get my head wrapped around all these concepts. If you don't mind, I would like to request some recommendations of resources which will allow me to understand async programming from the basics. Thank you again for your time. Absolutely appreciate it.
